# compare array values contains strings

Tags: powershell

I have two arrays of strings

```
$a1 = @('a123-xyz','b479-wer','cbchjk','lio_iuy')
$b1 = @('a123-xyz','b479-wer','cbc-hjk')
```

I want to compare `$a1` and `$b1` whatever element is not there in `$b1`, I have to get that.

I write like this:

```
$c1 = $a1 | Where {$b1 -NotContains $_}
```

`$c1` will contain `'cbchjk','lio_iuy'`.

Question:

`$al` and `$b1` contain "cbchjk" and "cbc-hjk". but there is a typo error in the `$a1` value. I am looking instead of saying "cbc-hjk" and "cbchjk" both are different (technically), I want to continue by auto-correcting the value of `$a1` and `$c1` should have only "lio_iuy"

Comment: Fuzzy matching is a very broad and complex topic. You need to provide far more information about what you want want matched as well as what you *don't* want matched. For example, removing hyphens and underscores from all values before performaing a comparison would allow producing the desired result *for these particular values*. The same approach will not work if for instance a letter or digit was mistyped.

Comment: thank you Ansgar for the reply. could you share some code samples for both options. It will be nice topic to learn.

Comment: Start by reading about [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Several implementations for the algorithm exist, including Powershell version.

Comment: thank you for the help.